# Remove the limit clause from MySQL Workbench

Tags: mysql, limit

I'm running this query: `select * from schema.table`

but i'm only getting the first 1000 rows

i see in the output window that there was a LIMIT clause appended to my select statement. Is there a way to turn off the default limit?

Comment: What tool are you using? (i.e.: What's adding the LIMIT clause?)

Comment: It seems like you are not running the query in direct mysql prompt. Is there any tool between?

Comment: ah, i see. there's also a button to toggle the limiting. Thanks!

Comment: by the way, post an answer if you want credit.

Answer (score 53, accepted):

You can toggle the LIMIT clause added by [MySQL Workbench](http://wb.mysql.com/) via the SQL Editor tab within the application preferences (Edit menu -> Preferences...).

Simply un-check the "Limit Rows" option within the Query Results section as pictured below.

[image: MySQL Workbench Preferences]

**EDIT:**

In Workbench 6.0, the "Limit Rows" checkbox stands in "SQL Queries" tab (new tab of the same form).

Answer (score 8):

### MySQL Workbench 6.3

#### Option 1

**Query** > **Limit Rows** > **Don't Limit**

[image: Query Limit Rows Don't Limit]

If you change the value here, it will also be **updated** in the path achievable via the second option.

#### Option 2

**Edit** > **Preferences...**

[image: Edit Preferences]

**SQL Editor** > **SQL Execution** > uncheck **Limit Rows**

[image: SQL Editor SQL Execution]

If you change the value here, it **won't be updated** in the path achievable via the first option, but the new value will be considered.

Answer (score 5):

In MySql Workbench 6.3 this option can be selected from the actual query window:
[image]

Answer (score 1):

In MYSQL Workbench 6.0 the option can be found at Edit->Preferences->SQL Queries tab.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `limit all` at the end of the query

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).