# query sql need to resolve

Tags: mysql, sql

In table keybank there's 100.000 terms, i want to make a sitemap list A, B, C, D
but it just showing data (id) from 1 to 5000 only not all 100.000 in group A, B, C, D

```
$data = 'A';
$where = "SELECT * FROM keybank WHERE left(title,1) = '".$data."' ORDER BY title ASC";
```

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: how to resolve it? using limit or range?

Comment: @soulfreeza It sounds like the opposite of his problem.

Comment: @Jonast92, soulfreeza is the op.

Comment: @ps2goat Right, good catch. Sounds like not a single clue is being given this day.

Comment: @soulfreeza Can you please show us how do you return this / where do you detect that only (I assume the first) 5000 rows are shown? Maybe the constraint is in there, as the query does not seem to limit the number of records by any means.

Comment: is it possible using this way ?

where AND id >='".$min."' AND id <= '".$max."'

Comment: are you looping and actually running this code for all four letters, A through D?

Comment: Please, read up on [proper SQL escaping](http://bobby-tables.com/php) because it looks like you're creating a giant [injection bug](http://bobby-tables.com/) here.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using MySQL workbench, maybe you have a default setting limiting the Query by default (Edit -> Preferences -> SQL Queries -> Untick "Limit Rows"). The credit goes to this post: [Remove the limit clause from MySQL Workbench](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5185348/remove-the-limit-clause-from-mysql-workbench) .

Also, you might alternatively try to append a `LIMIT 999999` at the end of your query to overwrite the default limit.

You could also try adding this before running your query: `SET SQL_SELECT_LIMIT=100000;`